# Get last received data after connect to BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an android app connects to BLE device and communicate together. after connect and bond app to device via BLE, and disconnect it, i receive last received packet and sometimes connect to device failed. see problem steps:
1. connect to ble device from android app.
2. write a characteristic successfully.
3. read a characteristic successfully.(last received data)
4. disconnect from ble device successfully.
5. try to connect app to ble device, i can't and i face below situation; even sometimes i connect but face below situation too:
I get last received data that i read from characteristic for last time.

Answer (score -1):

i can't find solution anywhere, so find solution and put it here, ENJOY!

I wrote this block of code and call it after disconnect:

```
public void disconnect() {
    if (mBluetoothGatt != null && isConnected()) {
        mBluetoothGatt.close();
        mBluetoothGatt = null;
    }
}
```

mBluetoothGatt is object from BluetoothGatt Class that implements BluetoothProfile. these classes and interfaces need information about implementation of ble in android app. search the web!